# Application stops working on mobile device but runs on emmulator

Tags: android, sqlite

i have developed an app for 'bank simulation' which uses sqlite to create databases...
when i run the app on my mobile it stops unexpectedly....do i need to install any server to run sqlite based apps on mobile?
Thanks in advance!

**DbHelper.java**

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "saket.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String SUBH_TABLE_NAME = "login";
public static final String SUBH_TABLE_DATA = "TBL_Transaction";
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
private static final String SUBH_TABLE_CREATE =
                "CREATE TABLE " + SUBH_TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+
                "username TEXT NOT NULL, password TEXT NOT NULL, email TEXT NOT NULL, balance INTEGER);";
private static final String SUBH_TABLE_DATA_CREATE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + SUBH_TABLE_DATA + "(" +
        "trans_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
        "user_id INTEGER, " +
        "trans TEXT NOT NULL);";

private static final String SAKET_DB_ADMIN = "INSERT INTO "+ SUBH_TABLE_NAME +" values(1, admin, password, admin@gmail.com);";
//private static final String SAKET_DB_ADMIN_Trans = "INSERT INTO "+ SUBH_TABLE_DATA +" values(1, asdf);";


public DbHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    System.out.println("In constructor");

}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper#onCreate(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase)
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    try{
        //Create Database
        db.execSQL(SUBH_TABLE_CREATE);

        //create transaction account
        db.execSQL(SUBH_TABLE_DATA_CREATE);

        //create admin account
        db.execSQL(SAKET_DB_ADMIN);

        //db.execSQL(SAKET_DB_ADMIN_Trans);

        System.out.println("In onCreate");
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**DatabaseActivity.java**

```
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mNewUser = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNewUser);
        mNewUser.setOnClickListener(this);

        mLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
        mLogin.setOnClickListener(this);

        mShowAll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonShowAll);
        mShowAll.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.buttonLogin:
            mUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editUsername);
            mPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPassword);

            String uname = mUsername.getText().toString();
            String pass = mPassword.getText().toString();

            if (uname.equals("") || uname == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username Empty",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (pass.equals("") || pass == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password Empty",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                boolean validLogin = false;
                try {
                    validLogin = validateLogin(uname, pass,
                            DatabaseActivity.this);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (validLogin) {
                    System.out.println("In Valid");
                    Intent i_login = new Intent(DatabaseActivity.this,
                            UserLoggedInPage.class);

                    try {
                        id = getID(uname, pass, DatabaseActivity.this);
                        Ubal = getBAL(uname, pass, DatabaseActivity.this);
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG, "putting the extra          " + id);
                    i_login.putExtra("key", id);
                    i_login.putExtra("bkey", Ubal);
                    startActivity(i_login);
                    finish();
                }
            }
            break;

        case R.id.buttonNewUser:
            Intent i = new Intent(DatabaseActivity.this, NewUserActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
            break;

        case R.id.buttonShowAll:
            Intent i_admin = new Intent(DatabaseActivity.this, AdminPage.class);
            startActivity(i_admin);
            finish();
            break;
        }
    }

    public boolean validateLogin(String uname, String pass, Context context)
            throws Exception {

        myDb = new DbHelper(context);
        SQLiteDatabase db = myDb.getReadableDatabase();
        // SELECT
        String[] columns = { "_id" };

        // WHERE clause
        String selection = "username=? AND password=?";

        // WHERE clause arguments
        String[] selectionArgs = { uname, pass };

        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            // SELECT _id FROM login WHERE username = uname AND password=pass
            cursor = db.query(DbHelper.SUBH_TABLE_NAME, columns, selection,
                    selectionArgs, null, null, null);

            startManagingCursor(cursor);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int numberOfRows = cursor.getCount();

        if (numberOfRows <= 0) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Login Failed..\nTry Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    // get rowid
    // public int getID(String uname, String pass, Context context)
    // throws Exception {
    //
    // myDb = new DbHelper(context);
    // SQLiteDatabase db = myDb.getReadableDatabase();
    // cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + DbHelper.SUBH_TABLE_NAME +
    // " where username = " + uname + "&" + "password = " + pass + ";)", null);
    // if (cursor != null) {
    // if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
    // int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_ROWID));
    // }
    //
    // }
    //
    // return id;
    //
    // }
    public String getID(String uname, String pass, Context context) {
        try {
            String idddd = null;
            SQLiteDatabase db = myDb.getReadableDatabase();

            String[] columns = { "_id" };

            // WHERE clause
            String selection = "username=? AND password=?";

            // WHERE clause arguments
            String[] selectionArgs = { uname, pass };

            Cursor cursor = db.query(DbHelper.SUBH_TABLE_NAME, columns,
                    selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null) {
                startManagingCursor(cursor);
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    idddd = cursor.getString(0);
                }
                return idddd;
            }
            System.out.println("Cursor NuLL");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return null;
    }

    private String getBAL(String uname, String pass,
            DatabaseActivity databaseActivity) {
        try {
            String ballll = null;
            SQLiteDatabase db = myDb.getReadableDatabase();

            String[] columns = { "balance" };

            // WHERE clause
            String selection = "username=? AND password=?";

            // WHERE clause arguments
            String[] selectionArgs = { uname, pass };

            Cursor cursor = db.query(DbHelper.SUBH_TABLE_NAME, columns,
                    selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null) {
                startManagingCursor(cursor);
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    ballll = cursor.getString(0);
                }
                return ballll;
            }
            System.out.println("Cursor NuLL");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (myDb != null && cursor != null ) {
            cursor.close();
            myDb.close();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: post the stacktrace and relevant code

Comment: Sqlite is a local system of storage so it doesn't need particular "server" to be installed. Anyway as said by @raghunandan without code or logat log we can't say what's your problem

Comment: Note that there is a client binary sqlite3 which is available on emulators and eng builds its not in the production buils, so if you use this instead of the java libs you will have an issue.

Comment: so if it works fine on my emulator then it must work on my mobile device without any installation?